# How do I calculate treasure parcels after Essentials?

Tags: dnd-4e, treasure

I was reading the Rules Compendium and it seems the way of calculating treasure has changed after Essentials came up. Considering English is not my first language and the fact everything got summarized in this book, I am a bit confused about how to distribute treasure.

How many Treasure Parcel rolls should I make between levels (meaning, before the characters lvl up so I can move to the next section of the table)? I guess this is around page 295 of the Rules Compendium.

Comment: I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the treasure parcel table is as follows:

You take the *contents* of the treasure parcels from the DMG an throw them out. Instead, for all of the parcels *you would otherwise award per this system* you roll on the table in the RC and award those parcels instead.

So the loot drops don't change, just what's in them.

Comment: In other words. 10 treasure parcels before the party levels up. Thanks